# Python string.replace is stripping off my quote characters

Tags: python, string, csv, replace

What I'm doing is feeding my python script a CSV file which contains millions of records separated by commas. Any strings are "contained by double qoutes".

I pass this .csv file through my python script

```
import csv
import string
import sys, getopt

inFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
outFile = open(sys.argv[1][:-4] + '_no-nulls.csv', 'w')
data = csv.reader(inFile)
writer = csv.writer(outFile)

specials = "NULL"

for line in data:
    line = [value.replace(specials, '') for value in line]
    writer.writerow(line)

inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

And the end result has all the quotes stipped off my strings.
What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

Sample input:

```
897555,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,NULL,"45687","B","QA",29,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"5648987QEXXX",6,NULL,NULL,"DOE","JOHN",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"Q",1994-04-24 00:00:00.000,"R","CX","ZZ",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"Y",NULL,"GA","R","DE",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"EN",NULL,"Y","OP",NULL,"R","XZ",NULL,NULL,NULL,"8945564",2005-03-01 12:00:00.000,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Sample output:

```
897555,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,,"45687","B","QA",29,,,,,,,,"5648987QEXXX",6,,,"DOE","JOHN",,,,,,"Q",1994-04-24 00:00:00.000,"R","CX","ZZ",,,,,,"Y",,"GA","R","DE",,,,,,"EN",,"Y","OP",,"R","XZ",,,,"8945564",2005-03-01 12:00:00.000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Are you sure those quotes are not field qualifiers?

Comment: They are. The .csv is an output from SQL which used QUOTENAME() on each text field.

Comment: And are you sure `csv.reader()` doesn't strip quotes from string input?

Comment: It is definitely not replace that is doing it, add some sample input

Comment: Try `print`ing the `repr()` of your data *before* replacing. I'd wager that the quotes are gone there already. Considering that your specials is a double-quote-delimited string (so it doesn't even contain double quotes), there's indeed no chance that replace is responsible.

Comment: See [`csv.QUOTE_ALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL). You might want to use it with the `writer`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham added sample input.

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham added expected output.

Comment: Try `writer = csv.writer(outFile), escapechar='\\', quoting=QUOTE_NONE)`, using QUOTE_NONE for the reader also

Comment: @PadraicCunningham But now I have \"This is a string\" in my results.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. When reading, `csv.reader` will strip off the quotes because it's assumed that the program consuming the data doesn't want or need them. `csv.writer` will then put them back on if necessary, depending on the setting of [`quoting`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quoting) that you pass, the default being `QUOTE_MINIMAL` - it will only add quotes if there are characters in the string that could be misinterpreted.

You could set both the reader and the writer to `QUOTE_NONE` to preserve the quotes that are in the original file, or set the writer to `QUOTE_ALL` to requote all output.

Comment: So adding `csv.writer(outFile, csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)` would do the trick?

Comment: Won't you need to set an escapechar?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I haven't actually tried it, so there might be a few nuances I missed.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think you would need something like `escapechar='\\'` with QUOTE_NONE.